# Apache Thrift Java-Javascript communication

Tags: javascript, java, thrift

I'm writing a Java server based on Apache Thrift, that will receive data from a Javascript client. I have completed the Java server, but the problem is that I can get a working example for the Javascript client (I was unable to find a good example for it). the examples in the build documentation aren't very helpful. My current Javascript client is below:

```
function testServer() {
    try {
        var transport = new Thrift.Transport("http://127.0.0.1:9090");
        var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
        var client = new JavaEventClient(protocol);

        var alive = client.isServerAlive();
    } catch(e) {
    }
}

testServer();
```

But the code isn't working - as the Java server throws an "Out Of Memory" Error. I don't know if the error is due to my client code or Apache Thrift.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the JVM memory?

Comment: Thrift in Java will maliciously throw an OOM on bogus input, it seems that JS client sends something wrong there. I suppose your protocol definition on the server-side has `isServerAlive()` method?

Comment: Yes, there is a declaration for isServerAlive() in the Java server implementation.

Comment: It seems that JS Thrift library is limited to JSON protocol only, is your server implemented using `JSONProtocol`?

Comment: No, How do I implement the server as JSONProtocol?

Comment: Here's an example: http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageJava

Comment: Sorry, Where do I put the serialization code?

Comment: OK, I'll reply back if I get it working. Thank you @favoretti

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem problem in communications. Maybe you use different protocol or transport on server and client. or bug in implementations of that protocols. // as example I found bug with utf8 characters in thrift-javascript serialization.

Please looks on https://github.com/imysak/using-thrift (My friend and I wrote this simple example of communication Java-Node.js via thrift).

I hope you can use something from our JS implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Out Of Memory` error occurs when your server is using `TBinaryProtocol` but you try to access it in another way, e.g. using a browser (which speaks HTTP). IMO that is a bug. There should be some nice error message instead.

The files how to make a Thrift Java server work with an Thrift Javascript client are scattered throughout the source. I puzzled them together here: https://github.com/LukeOwncloud/ThriftJavaJavascriptDemo